# ReactJS - Route update link but not refresh page

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a simple ReactJS page (my first one) and i'm having an issue with route. Link on browser bar is updated (no errors in console) but the page is not refreshed:

My `App.js` is:

```
return(
   <div id="container">
      <Dashboard>{this.props.children}</Dashboard>
   </div>
);
```

The Dashboard is the main page where the dynamic content is rendered on the middle

```
 return(
    <!-- code for navbar, sidebar etc -->
      ...
      <Link to="/memory">Memory</Link>
      ....
     <div id="page-wrapper" className="page-wrapper">
        {this.props.children}
     </div>
);
```

So i have created two small component (`Home` that is displayed at the beginning and `Memory`)

Home:

```
render() {
    return(
       <div className="row">
            HOMEPAGE
        </div>
    );
}
```

Memory:

```
  render() {
        return(
           <div className="row">
                MEMORY
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Router is very simple:

```
<Route component={App}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home}>
        <Route path='/memory' component={Memory} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

When i go to my home server (localhost:3000) my **HOMEPAGE** is displayed but when i click on `Memory` link nothing happen... the url change but `Memory` component is not rendered...

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the reply i have had this is a working version:

Dashboard -> deleted

App.js

```
 return(
    <div id="container">
      <div className="content" id="wrapper">
        <Navigation />
        <div id="page-wrapper" className="page-wrapper" >
          {this.props.children || <Home />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In this way Navigation will contain only the part relative to navigation (top bar and left side bar).

Route has been changed:

```
<Route>
   <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Route path='/memory' component={Memory} />
   </Route>
</Route>
```

Now when i go to home (localhost:3000) , the variable `this.props.children` is undefined and i render the Home component (thanks to `{this.props.children || <Home />}`).

In all other cases i render the right component provided by `Link`

Comment: What if you remove the `/` in your Router Memory route? So that line should then be `<Route path='memory' component={Memory} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

Routes:

```
   <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <Route path='/memory' component={Memory} />
    </Route>
   </Router>
```

And 'App' component:

```
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <Dashboard/>{this.props.children || <Home />}
      </div>
);
```

Don't forget, you need to connect 'Home' component in App. I can send you full working example.

Comment: In this way something happen, when click Memory the memory page is displayed... but at "full screen", i lost the Dashboard as container and the dymanic content that should go inside it...

Comment: @Mistre83 oh, i fix routes. Check now, please.

Comment: I've tried to make some change reading your code and with this i finally have had a working version! (i dont know if later i will have other issues :D) Check my update on the original thread

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the route path for your memory component doesn't require the leading slash. Other than that your setup is the same as mine.

```
 <Route path='memory' component={Memory} />
```

Comment: Nothing change, i did already tried this way :( What i have noticed is that if i go directly to localhost:8080/memory the request arrive to the server but the page is not refresh. If i go to Memory from link, request do not arrive on the server.....